# Pokemon Go logged out of my account

Tags: pokemon-go

I got logged out on Pokemon Go, but my mom sighned me up so I don't know the username password or email. I don't know if it is a pokemon trainer club account or google. All I know is the Nickname which is JewelsPanda. Is it possible to get my accout back?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you ask to your Mom? She probably knows if she created a trainer club account or not.

For my part, I log in with my main Gmail adress, never with the Username.

BTW, there's only 1 username (account) for an email adress.